# UITableView custom cell - How to keep cornerRadius in edit mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I implemented a tableview with custom cells. The cells have their cornerRadius set to 2. Everything displays just fine until I enter edit mode. When the delete button appears, it's corner radius is 0.

How can I make the delete button have a cornerRadius too?

I tried this without any luck:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell!.editingAccessoryView?.layer.cornerRadius = 2
}
```

[image]

The corner Radius is currently set as a User Defined Runtime Attribute in my Storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Please add User Defined Runtime Attribute for corner radius storyboard-screenshot as well.

Comment: Added it to my question

Comment: Also, try `cell.clipToBounds = true` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Not possible in cellForRowAtIndexPath with a custom cell... I set clipToBounds to true in my CustomCell.swift file. No change...

Answer (score 0):

you can manipulate the button like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
  var button1 = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
                  println("button1 pressed!")
              })


  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(button1.view.frame.size);
  [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  button1.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];

  return [button1]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
  return true
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}
```

Comment: Value of type 'UITableViewRowAction' has no member 'layer' - 

Does not work... Couldn't find a way to get the buttons View either

Comment: Ha... turns out the UITableViewRowAction does not inherit from UIButton... my bad... You have to use the backgroundColor property in that case. I will add some more code.

Comment: Edit done... I am on mobile so I can't test but it should be close.

Comment: Really appreciate the help! Great idea with the backGroundColor! Unfortunately UITableViewRowAction does not have a view property either. The only properties it does have are style, title, backgroundColor, backgroundEffect. None of those can be used to get the size...

Comment: Then you still use the backgroundColor but use images of the correct size...  Can't think of anything else...

Comment: thanks for your help :) I'll try around with the image. getting it right for different devices sounds a bit challenging when I have to guess the right size

Comment: So what did you end up doing?