# Corner Radius of UITableViewCell Being Reset when Editing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cornerradius

I have a UITableView that has a list of UITableViewCells with custom corner radii. When swiping to edit, e.g. delete/insert, the corner radius is reset back to 0.

[image: Image of cell's corner radius being reset]

I've tried to set the corner radius while editing:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? HabitTableViewCell else { return }
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 13
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        controller.delete(habit: frc.object(at: indexPath))
    }
}
```

I've also tried implementing willBeginEditingRowAt in a similar way to try to get the corner radius to stay set. The last thing I tried was creating a custom UIContextualAction in trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt, but it doesn't change anything.

There was a [similar question asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442819/uitableview-custom-cell-how-to-keep-cornerradius-in-edit-mode) about four years ago, but no conclusive solution was ever found. Any help or insight is appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you make 'cornerRadius' inside the 'UITableViewCell' with 'layoutSubviews' function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set corner radius and border to `contentView`.

```
cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 13
```

Add this code to `awakeFromNib` or `layoutSubviews` method of `UITableViewCell` class.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 13

    // Your border code here (set border to contentView)
    self.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    self.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 3
}
```